# immediate alert service alert level specification

Tags: android

I m working on an android application that connects to CC2541. I m able to see all services and characteristics of those services. I want to use Alert Level charasteristic of Immediate Alert Service. The last step of my appliation is that when i click to the alert level charc.
the buzzer should sound but i m not able to do this. Here is my code:

```
public void setCharacteristicNotification(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, boolean enabled) 
{
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) 
    {
        Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
        return;
    }
    mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, enabled);

    // This is specific to Alert Level.
    if (UUID_ALERT_LEVEL.equals(characteristic.getUuid())) 
    {
        characteristic.setValue("0x0028".getBytes());
        mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);
      /*  BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(UUID.fromString(SampleGattAttributes.CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG));
        descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
        mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);*/
    }
}
```

I m not sure to use writeCharacteristic() or writeDescriptior() to achieve that. I will appreciate any help.

http://imgur.com/OEs2s8z

Answer (score 0):

I have try on CC2541 , it can make the buzzer beep when I call the `writeAlertLevel` and give it the `alert level`.

For example , the `alert level` is `ALERT_HIGH`.

```
private static final int ALERT_HIGH = 2;
private static final UUID IMMEDIATE_ALERT_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001802-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
private static final UUID ALERT_LEVEL_UUID = UUID.fromString("00002a06-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");

public void writeAlertLevel(int level) {
BluetoothGattService alertService = mBluetoothGatt.getService(IMMEDIATE_ALERT_UUID);
if(alertService == null) {
Log.d(TAG, "Immediate Alert service not found!");
return;
}
BluetoothGattCharacteristic alertLevel = alertService.getCharacteristic(ALERT_LEVEL_UUID);
if(alertLevel == null) {
Log.d(TAG, "Alert Level charateristic not found!");
return;
}
alertLevel.setValue(level, BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8, 0);
mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(alertLevel);
}
```